# ¿cual es el puerto que utiliza el sensor GPS que viene en una tablet?

Tags: visual-studio, plugin

Queria consultar:
 ¿cual es el **puerto** que utiliza el sensor **GPS** que viene en una **tablet**?

Saludos

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes? Hasta donde yo se en windows 8 ya no se usan puertos para el GPS.... te esta dando problemas la comunicación?

Comment: Hola,, entonces, por cual medio puedo acceder al sensor gps de la tablet ?

Comment: googlea un poco :D . Me parece que va por API. Si quieres acceder al puerto creo que deberás virtualizarlo. Hay bastante información al respecto. Siento no ser más preciso, pero no se lo suficiente para guiarte más allá.